# JOIn by case Expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to perform this Code

```
select * from a
right join s
 on case when s.[Diff ] = 0   and  a.ActivityDate < s.[ExecDate]
 then a.ID1 =s.ID2
when
( a.ActivityDate <s.[ExecDate] and a.ActivityDate >= s.[Date3] ) 
then a.ID1 =s.ID2
END
```

Comment: Go ahead and perform it then. What's the question?

Comment: Case expression, not case statement...

Comment: Its now working on sql server 2012

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case is pointless. You join the same two fields ANYWAYS, so just add your case conditions to the join condition:

```
SELECT ...
JOIN ... ON ((a.ID1 = s.ID2) AND ((case #1) OR (case #2)))
```

Comment: I Tried this at start but i think it was the outer brackets i forgot to add,

Answer (score 1):

Just to elaborate on Marc's answer, I think the simplest form is:

```
select *
from a right join
     s
     on a.ID1 = s.ID2 and a.ActivityDate < s.[ExecDate] and
        (s.[Diff ] = 0 or a.ActivityDate >= s.[Date3])
```

Note that I do advise using `left join` instead of `right join`.  It is usually more intuitive to read a query thinking "all the rows in the first table are kept as well a matching rows in other tables."